# How to change wordpress query_posts arguments by clicking a link?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have an arguments to display my post using WP_query post. I have a link that is something a list of category items. For example, i have categories which is: Products,Services and Clients. When i click the Products it will automatically change my query post and if click the services automatically change into services posts. Also i want to add ajax for it to stop loading the page. How can i do it ? Please help me to do this. I am new in wordpress. Where would i add the ajax script ? and then change the click post to change the category.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => 'products',
        'posts_per_page' => '6',
    );
    $productsBlog = new WP_Query( $args );

    $count = 0;
    if( $productsBlog->have_posts() ) : 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this snippet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36128/103640)

Make sure you provide post_type argument in your ajax request if you use custom post types.

Add paged query variable to enable pagination.

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
// where $paged should be used in your arguments along with category_name,post_type_posts_per_page etc
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir.. I am a little bit of confusing. any tutorial to reccomend me sir ?.

Comment: Which section is confusing for you? Have you tried the snippet? Refer [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190655/load-categories-with-ajax) thread. It has detailed answer and code. Alternatively there is a plugin for your requirement called [AGP Ajax Taxonomy Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/agp-ajax-taxonomy-filter)

Comment: disregard the ajax first sir. i mean sir. when i will click a link, it will change my  'category_name' => 'products', from args

Comment: Without Ajax you can use [List categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) This will output list of categories, when you click a category it will show only posts in that specific category.